# Is it safe to call methods AutoResetEvent from different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

Is it safe to call methods AutoResetEvent from different threads?
Or should I avoid calls of the object from different threads?

```
class Test 
{
    EventWaitHandle wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Thread worker = new(Work);

    public Test
    {
        worker.Start();
    }

    public void StopSignal()
    {
        wh.Set(); //<-- Main thread Call
    }

    void Work() 
    {
        wh.WaitOne(); //<-- Child thread call
    }
}
```

Comment: It is designed to work (communicate) between threads. If it wasn't safe the WaitHandles would be useless.

Comment: you gonna have hard time picking the right answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it safe to call methods AutoResetEvent from different threads. Have a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39040/Auto-and-Manual-Reset-Events-Revisited). I hope this makes you clear.

Answer (score 3):

That's fine - it's kind of what it's meant to be used for!

See [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article for more info. There's a section called 'Thread Safety' near the bottom which is listed for most classes on MSDN, so if you're unsure about whether any other classes are thread safe in the future, you can just check there.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent is exactly to provide synchronisation between different threads!

see [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details.